# Does the equivalence $\mathsf{Set}^I\simeq \mathsf{Set}_{/I}$ rely on the extensivity of the category of sets?

Tags: category-theory

Given a family $i\mapsto X_i$ we may co-restrict to obtain a bijection $I\cong \amalg_i \left\{ X_i \right\} $. This coproduct admits a set-function to $I$ given by $\left\{ X_i \right\} \mapsto i$. Conversely, a bundle $X\to I$ realizes the bundle $\amalg _iX_i\to I$ where the $X_i$ are the fibers. From the coproduct we define $i\mapsto \iota_iX_i$ picking out the $i^\text{th}$ summand. Evidently these assignments are mutually inverse.

This bijection can be refined to an equivalence of categories $\mathsf{Set}^I\simeq \mathsf{Set}_{/I}$ between $I$-indexed families (of constant sets) and bundles over $I$ (variable sets). I am trying to construct this equivalence "from above", i.e using properties of the category of sets only. I came up with the following string, where the penultimate equivalence relies on extensivity and the final isomorphism relies on the fact sets are discrete, i.e each set is a coproduct of singletons.

$$\begin{aligned} \; [\operatorname{disc}I,\mathsf{Set}] & \cong [\amalg_i\mathbf{1},\mathsf{Set}]\\ & \cong \prod_i[\mathbf{1},\mathsf{Set}] \\
& \cong \prod_i\mathsf{Set} \\ & \cong \prod_i \mathsf{Set}_{/ \left\{ i \right\}  }  \\  & \simeq \mathsf{Set}_{/ \amalg_i \left\{ i \right\} } \\ & \cong \mathsf{Set}_{/I}. \end{aligned}$$

It seems sensible for "discreteness of objects" to be involved - we're explicitly decomposing the total space of a bundle to a coproduct of its fibers (and of course the result does not hold when $\operatorname{disc}I$ is replaced with a "cohesive" category such as the fundamental groupoid of a non-discrete space). I am wondering though whether it is possible to avoid the use of extensivity.

Comment: Aside: this is true for every category $C$ and every object $X$ of $C$. Admittedly that's a bit of a cheat, since in general, $C^X$ is *defined* to be $C_{/X}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl as far as I'm aware, the notation $C^X$ denotes an internal hom of arrows from $X$ to $C$.